# Filtering a dataframe on values in 2 columns

Tags: r

I wish to filter a dataframe based on the values of 2 columns, so in the example below if we see more than one location under a number/code I wish to pull out all of that information.

```
mynewdf
code        location
101         london
101         london
102         manchester
102         manchester
102         bolton
102         oldham
102         oldham
103         leeds
103         huddersfield
103         leeds
104         sheffield
104         sheffield
105         hull
```

So here im trying to pull out any codes where the code and location where the location is 2 of more seperate locations, what im trying to get is a new df looking like;

```
mynewdf
code        location
102         manchester
102         manchester
102         bolton
102         oldham
102         oldham
103         leeds
103         huddersfield
103         leeds
```

I thought about trying to do this by uniquing my df and looking for any duplicates of the code column but wasn't very successful as I think duplicate doesn't return all the values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## base R

```r
mynewdf[with(mynewdf, ave(location, code, FUN = function(z) length(unique(z)) > 1) == "TRUE"),]
#    code     location
# 3   102   manchester
# 4   102   manchester
# 5   102       bolton
# 6   102       oldham
# 7   102       oldham
# 8   103        leeds
# 9   103 huddersfield
# 10  103        leeds
```

## dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
mynewdf |>
  filter(.by = code, n_distinct(location) > 1)
#   code     location
# 1  102   manchester
# 2  102   manchester
# 3  102       bolton
# 4  102       oldham
# 5  102       oldham
# 6  103        leeds
# 7  103 huddersfield
# 8  103        leeds
```

This is using `dplyr_1.1.0`; if you have an older version, replace the `.by=c(..)` with `group_by(..)` before the verb.

Comment: i deleted my answer. I misunderstood at first.  Your `base R` IS the accurate version of what I gave. Thank you for helping see my error.